# In light of the larger context surrounding Matt 10:28, Who is it that the disciples should fear?

Tags: matthew, contradiction, jesus, authorial-intent, context

**Matt 10:28** - *And fear not them which kill the body, but are not able to kill the soul: but rather fear him which is able to destroy both soul and body in hell.*

It seems the **general consensus regarding this verse** is that the Father God is the one who is to be feared, not evil men who would Martyr the disciples bodily.

Contextually to me **it seems like a forced interpretation** due to the fact that immediately following this verse, it names the Father in reference to paying attention to them with specificity/loving care, and says, specifically regarding the  Father - not to fear.

***QUESTION***:  **Please address why you think it is or is not the Father God who the readers are to "fear".  If it is not the Father, who do you believe it is referring to?**